# React js cant interpret axios call the right way, data is undefined

Tags: reactjs, axios

When I perform a REST call (get) with axios from my react app, it says that the response is undefined. But when I try to do the same call in Postman, it clearly gives the right response. React cannot get the right response. How do I resolve this problem?

Response gives 'undefined' and response.data also gives 'undefined'.

```
class Blogpost extends React. Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
const response = axios.get({
      URL: 'http://178.62.198.162/api/posts',
      headers: {'token' : 'pj11daaQRz7zUIH56B9Z'}
    })
    const items = response.data;
    this.setState({
      isLoaded: false,
      items: items,
    });
    console.log(this.items);
  }

render() {
    const {error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <ul>
          {this.items.map(item => (
            <li key={item.name}>
            {item.name}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The expected result would be an array of collections. But actually it is given back 'undefined'.

How can I make it work so response gives the right array?

**EDIT**
There seems to be a problem with the GET request. The promise gets rejected with fail code 404.

```
componentDidMount() {
const response = axios.get({
  URL: 'http://178.62.198.162/api/posts',
  headers: {'token' : 'pj11daaQRz7zUIH56B9Z'}
})
response.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

}

Is this a problem on the server side, or on the client side and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Hi Nynke! sarabs3 and I both provided answers for you to solve this problem. Honestly, both should work. Let us know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi Christopher,

There seems to be a problem with the promise. It gets rejected with fail code 404. I do not know if this is a server side problem or client side. Also because the call seems to work just fine in postman...

Answer (score 1):

You are using axios wrong way. Axios always returns a Promise object.

Change your code to following and it will work.

```
componentDidMount() {
const response = axios.get({
      URL: 'http://178.62.198.162/api/posts',
      headers: {'token' : 'pj11daaQRz7zUIH56B9Z'}
    })
    response.then((res) => {
      const items = res.data;
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: false,
        items: items,
      });
      console.log(this.items);
    }
})

  }
```

You can read more about Promises here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Hi Nynke, As your API is giving 404 error, you have already used `catch()` method of promise. that will handle the UI. and 404 error is basically either you are not calling the API endpoint currently or your server is not running.  e.g. `http://178.62.198.162/api/posts` this link is not working. Not an issue with frontend

Answer (score 1):

you should use async/await syntax to make sure response variable will be filled with right http get response before initializing

```
async componentDidMount() { 
  const response = await axios.get({
    URL: 'http://178.62.198.162/api/posts',
    headers: {'token' : 'pj11daaQRz7zUIH56B9Z'}
  })
  const items = response.data;
  this.setState({
  isLoaded: false,
  items: items,
});
}
```